# Eslint: no-duplicates Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, eslint

I just updated my project(SPA with VueJS and Quasar Framework) today with `npm update` and I can't now run it.

I am getting error `no-duplicates  Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node"` in many different modules. It is always pointing 1:1

I have no idea what is going on as it was all working fine before...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node is needed?

Comment: Will try first thing in the morning

Answer (score 6):

I had to explicitly install [`eslint-import-resolver-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node)

```
npm install -D eslint-import-resolver-node
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped also with yarn as a package manager with PnP enabled
`yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-node`

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, I think some dependancies have been removed to fix I did

> npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev
>
> npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

Then I edited .eslintrs.js

modify extends to look like this

```
  extends: [
    'standard',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    ],
```

add the import plugin like

```
  plugins: [
    'html',
    'import'
  ],
```

then add the following rules

```
'import/named': 2,
'import/namespace': 2,
'import/default': 2,
'import/export': 2,
```

You then also have to modify where you import quasar

for example it looked like this before

```
import Quasar from 'quasar'
```

Now you have to do

```
import Quasar from 'quasar-framework'
```

Comment: I am using `airbnb`. I suppose I will replace `standard` with `airbnb` in `extends` section?

Answer (score 0):

restart your project it will be fix
if not remove node_modules and reinstall

## remove node_modules and npm install