# "Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node""

Tags: meteor, npm, eslint, standardjs

I have spent the day wrestling with standardJS and package.json in a project.

Just when I thought I had [fixed some no-def issues](https://github.com/unee-t/frontend/commit/4674f13b6376929821c4b7eb3926f1d33048adba) when upgrading to standard 11, I now face multiple:

```
error  Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node"  import/no-duplicates
```

So going to back to basics, do I really need "eslint" installed for standardJS to work? The project does seem to require "babel-eslint" for some [arrow functions to work](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/935).

Is there anything else I can do to try resolve these [CI errors](https://travis-ci.org/unee-t/frontend/builds/396325916)?

Maybe it's a Travis issue, or a `npm i` and `meteor npm i` issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint: no-duplicates Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865507/eslint-no-duplicates-resolve-error-unable-to-load-resolver-node)

Answer (score 2):

I had to explicitly install [`eslint-import-resolver-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node). There was a recent update to the `eslint-plugin-import` that did not correctly link `eslint-import-resolver-node`. The following command will install the missing package and get things working:

```
npm install -D eslint-import-resolver-node
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, npm 6 install was messing around with `meteor npm`'s in-built version at 4. The CI fix was to override the [default Travis install phase](https://github.com/unee-t/frontend/commit/5c36e778f8d5963112524f7d6d45db08dba20edd).

Nonetheless I am still wondering if I need eslint dependency in my project.